# Show tooltip hover on image using knockoutjs

Tags: image, knockout.js, hover, tooltip

I want to bind text in span tag but visible=false, and hover on image show span text in tooltip.

```html
<td class="calign"><img src="~/Images/Approval.png" height="15" width="15" alt="" data-bind="tooltip:ApprovalText" /></td>
```

Tooltip can't display on image hover.

Answer (score 15):

Bind to the `title` attribute instead of `tooltip` (which isn't a valid html attribute):

```
data-bind="attr:{title:ApprovalText}"
```

Comment: Bang on ! but i'm confused why you got a downVote . possible attach a fiddle(http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/26682/) which helps the OP .

Comment: adding a whole fiddle to replace the only data-bind attribute used in their code doesn't add much

Comment: apparently I've gotten two downvotes for giving a correct answer

Comment: @dfperry Your answer is great, but If we want to add css for tooltip. Any Idea?

Comment: @PrabhatMaurya you can't style an html tooltip. to get that kind of functionality, you'd need to use a third-party library